# update file based on a key in C

Tags: c, file-handling

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct person 
{
    char  name[10];
    char size[6];
    char timestamp[15];
};
  
int main ()
{
    FILE *outfile;
      
    // open file for writing
    outfile = fopen ("ads.txt", "a");
    if (outfile == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nError opend file\n");
        exit (1);
    }
  
    struct person input1 = {"runner", "100", "4376482682"};
    //struct person input2 = {"maze", "300", "3232365436"};
      
    // write struct to file
    fwrite (&input1, sizeof(struct person), 1, outfile);
    //fwrite (&input2, sizeof(struct person), 1, outfile);
      
    if(fwrite != 0) 
        printf("contents to file written successfully !\n");
    else 
        printf("error writing file !\n");
  
    // close file
    fclose (outfile);
  

     FILE *infile;
    struct person input;

    infile = fopen ("ads.txt", "r");
    if (infile == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nError opening file\n");
        exit (1);
    }
      
    // read file contents till end of file
    char name[10] = "maze";
    char size[6] = "500";
    char timestamp[15] = "437838322";
    int remaining_size = 100;
    int alreadythere =0;
    //unpcoming file size
    int incoming_file_size = 200;
    int target_file_size_toremove = incoming_file_size - remaining_size;
    while(fread(&input, sizeof(struct person), 1, infile)){
        if(target_file_size_toremove > 0) {
            int x = atoi(input.size);
            if(target_file_size_toremove < x) {
                strcpy(input.name, name);
                strcpy(input.size, size);
                strcpy(input.timestamp, timestamp);
            }
        }else {
        if(strcmp(input.name, name) == 0) { // if name is eqUAL
            if(strcmp(input.size, size) != 0) {
                strcpy(input.size, size);
            }
            if(strcmp(input.timestamp, timestamp) !=0) {
                strcpy(input.timestamp, timestamp);
            }
        alreadythere = 1;
        }
        printf ("id = %s name = %s %s\n", input.name,
        input.size, input.timestamp);
    }
    }
    if(alreadythere == 0) {
        struct person incoming = {name, size, timestamp};
        fwrite (&incoming, sizeof(struct person), 1, outfile);
    }
    // close file
    fclose (infile);
    return 0;
}
```

The code is in C language. I want to update the `size` variable when name is equal to "maze". How I can do it, while reading from file?

**first the data that is writing in file is -**
runner    100   4376482682
maze      300   3232365436

**After updating -**
runner    100   4376482682
maze      100   3232365436

*size should updated from 300 to 100.*

Comment: If you want to write raw structures with `fwrite` then you must open the file in *binary* mode. I.e. `fopen("ads.txt", "wb")`. The same when reading it of course, in needs to be opened in `"rb"` mode. But remember, even if you called the file `.txt` it's not really a text file.

Comment: Also, `if(fwrite != 0)` is not how you check if `fwrite` succeeded or not. The condition `fwrite != 0` will *always* be true, as you compare the *function pointer* to a null pointer.

Comment: So how can I update that, if I am opening that in binary mode?

Comment: Get current position in file. Read the structure. Modify the structure. Seek back to the stored position. Write the structure.

Comment: What are you expecting the `printf` conversion specifier `%d` (signed integer) to do with the `char*` `input.name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed a number of small bugs in your code related to opening the file in correct mode and checking if `fwrite` and `fread` where successful. Then I added the part you where really asking: update the record "maze".

To update the record, we need to read it, change the value and write it back to the file exactly where we have read it. So before reading a record, we query the current file pointer with `ftell` and before writing, we call `fseek` to move the file pointer back to the place we read. A call to `fflush` (another `fseek` would do as well) is required so that the next `fread` take place at the correct position.

For testing, I added a third record after "maze" so that we can see - by looking at the file content - that we don't overwrite data.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct person
{
    char name[10];
    char size[6];
    char timestamp[15];
};

int main()
{
    FILE* outfile;

    // open file for writing binary
    outfile = fopen("ads.txt", "wb");  
    if (outfile == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nError opening file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    struct person input1 = { "runner", "100", "4376482682" };
    struct person input2 = { "maze",   "300", "3232365436" };
    struct person input3 = { "street", "400", "4232365486" };

    // write struct to file, checking for success
    if ((fwrite(&input1, sizeof(struct person), 1, outfile) != 1) ||
        (fwrite(&input2, sizeof(struct person), 1, outfile) != 1) ||
        (fwrite(&input3, sizeof(struct person), 1, outfile) != 1))
        printf("error writing file !\n");
    else
        printf("contents to file written successfully !\n");

    // close file
    fclose(outfile);


    FILE* infile;
    struct person input;

    // Open for both reading and writing, binary
    infile = fopen("ads.txt", "r+b");
    if (infile == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nError opening file for update\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // read file contents till end of file, update "maze"
    while (1) {
        long pos = ftell(infile);
        if (pos < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "\nError getting file position\n");
            break;
        }
        if (fread(&input, sizeof(struct person), 1, infile) != 1)
            break;
        // update the value of size here, if name is equal to "maze"
        printf("id = %s name = %s %s\n", input.name, input.size, input.timestamp);
        if (strcmp(input.name, "maze") == 0) {
            if (fseek(infile, pos, SEEK_SET) != 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "\nError moving file pointer\n");
                break;
            }
            strcpy(input.size, "100");
            if (fwrite(&input, sizeof(struct person), 1, infile) != 1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "\nError writing file\n");
                break;
            }
            // fflush() is required so that fread() take place a the correct position
            if (fflush(infile) != 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "\nError flushing file\n");
                break;
            }
            printf("  Updated id = %s name = %s %s\n", input.name, input.size, input.timestamp);
            // Since this code update a single record, we could break the loop
        }
    }

    // close file
    fclose(infile);
    return 0;
}
```